# Unable to access my constant/final String array values declared in a Java interface

Tags: java, interface, nullpointerexception, constants, final

So I have an interface, it's got a few constant integers declared and I can access these in any class which implements said interface.

I just declared an array of constant strings in the interface, and I tried to access it, resulting in a null pointer expression, my array is declared like so:

```
public static final String[] STRINGS = {"bla","bla","bla","bla", "bla", "bla"};
```

In the test program, the following line returns a NullPointerException:

```
System.out.println(STRINGS[1]);
```

So, my question: Is there any problem here, or can you only work with integer constants in an interface?

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame implements MyInterface {
....
....
private static JCheckBox[] checkBoxes = new JCheckBox[NUMBER];
....
....
int counter = 0;
        for (JCheckBox box : checkBoxes) {
            box.setText(STRINGS[counter]);
            box.setSelected(false);
            checkBoxPane.add(box);
            counter++;
        }

 ....
```

The above code shows the test class, NUMBER and STRINGS are declared in MyInterface, I've changed the names for simplicity.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can we see your complete code, pls ?

Comment: "can you only work with integer constants in an interface?" No.

Comment: Where is Test class code

Comment: The class is 500 lines long but I will get the relevant lines now

Comment: Hie, I just tested it here, it work as expected, i can access the static strings as if it was declare in implementing class. The problem is elsewhere

Comment: Note that this isn't really a constant array. Anyone can do `Constants.STRINGS[1] = null;`. To guarantee immutability, you should use `List<String> STRINGS = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList("bla", "bla"));`

Comment: Thanks for the tip JB. 
Edits made to the question guys

Comment: Even though it is possible, I would advise _against_ declaring variables in interfaces. You can create custom classes for that.

Comment: What's the complete exception stack trace?

Comment: @user2253489  Are you sure every box in the array is not null?

Comment: Items in `STRINGS` array won't be immutable and it should work just fine. As others said there might be something wrong else where, post the a bit more of the exception stack.

Comment: Thanks guys, for some reason it works when I moved the 
'= new JCheckBox...'
part into the actual program rather than the declarations at the top

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elements in an `Object` array are `null` by default. Ensure that each `JCheckBox` is initialized before attempting to invoke a method on the component

```
for (int i=0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
    checkBoxes[i] = new JCheckBox();
}
```

Comment: I thought I initialized the array in the same line they were declared, but I moved the = new JCheckBox(NUMBER) into the functions of the program and it worked. Cheers

Comment: From the code above only the array not the elements appears to be initialized

Comment: @user2253489: lesson to learn: always read/post the stack trace of the exception, which tells what and where the problem is, instead of assuming it has to do with constants in interfaces or anything else.

Comment: To be fair I posted it was a null pointer exception, which was the only useful part of the stack trace. I was confused as I did initialize the boxes (or thought I did!), so I assumed it was an interface problem, as I only recently discovered interfaces could hold variables!

Answer (score 2):

This woks perfectly ok.

```
public interface Trail {
    public static final String[] STRINGS = {"bla","bla","bla","bla", "bla", "bla"};
}
```

Implementation

```
public class X implements Trail{
    public void get() {
        System.out.println(STRINGS[1]);
    }
}

public class TEstMain {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    X x = new X();
    x.get();
}
```

Output:

```
bla
```